# How to Change from BIOS to UEFI on Asus P8Z77-V LX with Windows 7x64

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, bios, uefi

My machine has an Asus P8Z77-V LX motherboard with Windows 7 x64 and is currently running in BIOS.

I am interested to switch to UEFI so the system will accept drives over 2TB.

Now, I know this motherboard has both modes; can I just switch and expect everything to work?  Reinstalling Windows is not an option as I have a really intricate, detailed profile that I don't want to rebuild.

Comment: Unless you want to boot from those drives, you can use GPT whenever you like though?

Comment: You are using the UEFI, although using a BIOS compatibility mode. Your hard drive is using MBR (master boot record) that limits it's size and number of partitions. You'd need to switch to GPT (GUID partition table). There is a way to convert MBR to GPT but I think you can't do that while Windows is running off of it.

Comment: Connect another HDD and install OS if you do not want to reinstall.

Comment: This doesn't sound like an easy fix to change to UEFI.  @DanielB yes, I know I can partition them - I just don't want to.

Comment: @GiantTree If I convert MBR to GPT, won't it break my Windows boot?

Comment: @bgmCoder yes, that's why you can't convert a Windows boot drive. Data drives work, though.

Comment: You always have partitions, even if it's only one. Now, to clarify: Is the drive that is larger than 2 TB the drive Windows is currently installed on?

Comment: Right now I can't load a 4TB disk without partitioning it, as I understand it is because I am using BIOS instead of UEFI.  The boot drive is under 2TB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of this has already been stated in comments, but I think it's useful to put it all in one place....

You *can* use an over-2TiB disk on a BIOS-booted version of Windows *if* the over-2TiB disk is a non-boot data disk. That is, you'd boot in BIOS mode from an under-2TiB disk and use the 2TiB disk for data. ("Data" can include not just user data, but program files, if you choose to store them there.) This is likely to be the easiest solution to your problem if you can add the new disk to an existing configuration. OTOH, if you must replace an existing disk with a bigger one, you'll need some other solution....

The best approach in such cases is likely to be to switch the machine to boot in EFI/UEFI mode. Since you're talking about a new disk, you'll need some way to clone your existing installation to it, and either simultaneously or afterwards, convert the installation to boot in EFI mode. EFI-mode booting more-or-less requires use of the GUID Partition Table (GPT), but converting from the older Master Boot Record (MBR) partitioning system to GPT is only half the battle; you must also install an EFI-mode boot loader for Windows. Microsoft has a new tool as part of its latest Windows 10 update that's supposed to do this -- it both converts a disk from MBR to GPT and installs an EFI-mode boot loader. See [Microsoft's page on the tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt) for details. Note that the tool is officially for Windows 10; but the language Microsoft uses ("Offline conversion of system disks with earlier versions of Windows installed, such as Windows 7, 8, or 8.1 are not officially supported") implies that it might work -- but do so at your own risk. Note that I've never used Microsoft's tool, so I can't comment on it from personal experience. In your position, I'd probably do a BIOS-mode disk clone (which would use just 2TiB of your disk's capacity), test that it works, and then try the BIOS/MBR-to-EFI/GPT conversion using Microsoft's tool. If it fails, you'd still have your original disk, so you could try again or try something else. After the conversion, you could expand your disk partition(s) to fill the extra disk space.

There used to be pages that describe how to do this type of conversion manually; however, the two pages I used to reference have both gone offline. There may be other such pages, but I haven't looked for them.

Of course, doing a completely fresh re-installation in EFI mode is another option. You could then transfer your personal files from your existing disk.

Note also that this boot-mode conversion assumes that your computer has EFI firmware, not the older BIOS firmware. Manufacturers switched from BIOS to EFI in droves in late 2011; most computers sold after that point are EFI-based, even if they boot using the Compatibility Support Module (CSM; aka legacy boot mode), which enables an EFI to emulate a BIOS. If your computer is from early 2011 or earlier, it's more likely to be a pure BIOS-only system, although you might be lucky and have an early EFI-mode system. If the computer is BIOS-only, you'll need to find another solution....

One such approach is [this one,](http://reboot.pro/topic/19516-hack-bootmgr-to-boot-windows-in-bios-to-gpt/page-2#entry184489) which describes a way to boot Windows from a GPT disk in BIOS mode. This is something I've never tried; I just happen to have run across the reference, and it might be of interest to you so I'm sharing it.

There are other options, too. Most notably, if the disk is under 4TiB, you could partition it such that everything above the 2TiB mark (and at least a bit before), but not exceeding 2TiB, is in one partition, with the rest of the disk partitioned as you like. For instance, with a 4TB (slightly under 4TiB) disk, you might make two 2TB partitions. This approach works because MBR records partition data in the form of partition start points and sizes. Each of those two values is limited to 2TiB, so it's technically legal in MBR for a partition to begin at just under 2TiB and be 2TiB in size -- hence, a 4TiB limit. Many OSes can't handle disks set up in this way, but Windows 7 seems OK with it, at least in my very limited testing. (See [my page on such workarounds.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/workarounds.html)) OTOH, my testing was very limited; you might run into serious problems -- and "serious problems" in this context could include data-eating complications. Thus, it's probably better to try something else, unless you're desperate.

One final, exceedingly complex, solution is to use [Clover](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cloverefiboot/) or [DUET.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/bios2uefi/) These are basically EFI implementations that can be run like BIOS-mode boot loaders. Using one of these tools, you could run Microsoft's conversion tool or re-install Windows to get the system booting in EFI mode. You shouldn't even think about using this approach if your computer boots natively in EFI mode, though; this is a desperate last-ditch way to get a BIOS-mode computer to boot Windows off an over-2TiB disk.

Overall, then, you have several options. Your best is to use the new disk as a secondary disk, without changing the way you boot. If you can't do that, I'd suggest using Microsoft's tool to convert from BIOS/MBR to EFI/GPT, provided your firmware is an EFI rather than an old-school BIOS. Beyond that, you're into flaky stuff that I can't recommend in most cases, but that might interest you if you've got some very special situation or if you just like to play on the bleeding edge.

Comment: Wow, that's the best answer I could dream of!  Thank you!  
Okay, so I'm actually only interested in using a 4TB secondary HDD, perhaps even external, and I don't want to mess with my running profile at all.  But right now it doesn't recognize the disk unless I partition it to 2TB.  Is there some setting I've missed?

Comment: One thing that works in your favor is that external USB drives use 4KiB sector sizes, which raises the MBR limit from 2TiB to 16TiB. Thus, you should be fine even with MBR on an external disk. There is one big caveat, though: Older enclosures don't do this sector-size translation and misbehave badly if you use an over-2TiB disk, so be sure to either buy an external 4TB disk or use a 4TB disk in an enclosure that does the necessary sector-size translation.

Comment: You are right - I bought a new WD MyBook 4TB and Windows 7 reads the full volume no problem.  It must be the enclosure which allows the reading of the full size.  When I tried with a Seagate 4TB  (green, I think) I couldn't read the full volume, but I was just using an external HDD dock; maybe that dock doesn't translate what is necessary to render the volume size.